# Xamarin Forms Nested flex layout with other controls not rendering properly

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to render a button inside nested `FlexLayout`, it's not getting resized automatically.

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <FlexLayout
            AlignItems="Center"
            Direction="Row">
            <StackLayout>
                <FlexLayout BackgroundColor="LightBlue" Direction="Column">
                    <Label FontSize="Medium" Text="Sample Test Column" />
                    <Label FontSize="Medium" Text="Sample Employee Column" />
                </FlexLayout>
            </StackLayout>
            <Button BackgroundColor="Green" Text="Submit" />
        </FlexLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Which property to modify to render the green button as shown properly. I don't want to give any specific `Width` and `Height` it should automatically adjust according to text of button.

[image]

Comment: Why are you wrapping the FlexLayouts in StackLayout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change `FlexLayout.Grow="1"` to your `FlexLayout` and remove the `StackLayout` like below:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <FlexLayout
        AlignItems="Center"
        Direction="Row">
            <FlexLayout  FlexLayout.Grow="1" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" Direction="Column" >
                    <Label FontSize="Medium" Text="Sample Test Column" />
                    <Label FontSize="Medium" Text="Sample Employee Column" />
                </FlexLayout>

            <Button  BackgroundColor="Green" Text="Submit" />
        </FlexLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: Is there any way to auto adjust height, if I don't keep parent flex-layout inside stack layout it takes complete screen height.